# Workbox.js registerNavigationRoute not finding/loading html file

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, server-side-rendering, workbox

I'm almost fully set up as a pwa with an app shell architecture, using a react like frontend (but using mithril as the rendering engine) with an express node.js backend and ssr, but struggling to get past on last issue.

UPDATE: we are also using fastly for caching and as our cdn. it's all disabled on dev, but maybe some headers are sneaking through and screwing with things?

I'm using registerNavigationRoute to register my html file that is also cached via precache and workbox-build. my service worker registers fine when on first load or a hard refresh, but when i try to do a regular refresh i get this error message

```
The FetchEvent for "http://localhost:8000/article/35474-a-fear-of-heights-
doesn-t-stop-this-dad-from-seeing-a-thrilling-view" resulted in a network 
error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to 
respondWith().
Promise resolved (async)
self.addEventListener @ router.js:140
```

and right around line 140 of the router.js file i see this message

```
message: 'The router is managing a route with a response.',
```

so i'm guessing that my node routes is screwing with it? i'm not totally sure though, any help would be appreciated!

here is my build setup

```
gulp.task "serviceworker", ->
  options =
    globDirectory: "./dist/app/"
    swSrc: "./dist/app/workbox.js"
    swDest: "./dist/app/service-worker.js"
    globPatterns: [
      "shell.html"
      "head.js"
      "client.js"
      "ads.client.js"
      "css\/inline.css"
      "css\/main.css"
      "icons\/*.png"
      "favicons\/*.png"
      "fonts\/{oswald,pt-sans,icomoon}*.woff2"
    ]

   options.dontCacheBustUrlsMatching = /icomoon\.woff2$/

   unless debug
     options.dontCacheBustUrlsMatching = /(icomoon\.woff2|\.(js|css))$/

   workboxbuild.injectManifest(options).then () ->
     console.log "Service workers generated."
   .catch (err) ->
     console.log "[ERROR] This happened: #{err}"
```

and here is my navigation route

```
 workboxSW.router.registerNavigationRoute("shell.html", {
     cacheName: "inverse-shell",
     whitelist: [
         /^\/$/,
         /^\/(article|channel)/,
         /^\/(science|mind-and-body|culture|innovation|entertainment)$/
     ],
     blacklist: [
        /^\/(sitemap|feed|amp|inews)/,
        /^\/(user|about|archive|browse|search)/,
        /^\/(newsletter|privacy-policy|terms-of-service|dmca)$/
    ]
});
```

UPDATE: and here is a link to my fully generated sw.js file https://gist.github.com/nikse/11c531382f136e703bf20648f9421948

Comment: Can you share a link to a publicly-accessible version of your PWA? If not, can you share the configuration you're using work workbox-build, and the final `sw.js` file that you're deploying?

Comment: hey @JeffPosnick, sorry! i hit publish too early!! question is fully updated w/ examples and error message

Comment: also @JeffPosnick this is still in development, so no public links but i am happy to send any files your way that you'd like to check out. thanks a lot!

Comment: any advice on this @JeffPosnick? been fuddling around with it for a few days with no lead

Comment: Sorry, I missed your updates. Could you try removing the `cacheName: "inverse-shell"` setting for your `registerNavigationRoute()`? Your `shell.html` isn't in the cache with that name—it's in the cache used for things passed to `precache()`, and that's already the default place that `registerNavigationRoute()` looks.

Comment: it worked! thanks a lot! sorry for the extra @

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Moving this from the comments to the answer.)

Your call to `registerNavigationRoute()` looks like:

```
workboxSW.router.registerNavigationRoute("shell.html", {
  cacheName: "inverse-shell",
  whitelist: [...],
  blacklist: [...]
});
```

Could you try removing the `cacheName: 'inverse-shell'` setting for your `registerNavigationRoute()`? Your shell.html isn't in the cache with that name—it's in the cache used for things passed to `precache()`, and that's already the default place that `registerNavigationRoute()` looks.